# How should I convert a string containing unicode characters to unicode?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, python-unicode

I thought that I dominated all the Unicode stuff in Python 2, but it seems that there's something I don't understand. I have this user input from HTML that goes to my python script:

```
a = "m\xe9dico"
```

I want this to be `médico` (that means doctor). So to convert that to unicode I'm doing:

```
a.decode("utf-8")
```

Or:

```
unicode(a, "utf-8")
```

But this is throwing:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can achieve this?

Comment: That's already unicode. The utf-8 version would be 'm\xc3\xa9dico'.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: in Python 3 that would be a unicode literal, but this is Python 2 so it's 8-bit data and hence Latin-1 at best. Ofc that's a Unicode-compatible encoding but I think misleading to just call it "unicode".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not utf-8:

```
print txt.decode('iso8859-1')
Out[14]: médico
```

If you want utf-8 string, use:

```
txt.decode('iso8859-1').encode('utf-8')
Out[15]: 'm\xc3\xa9dico'
```

Comment: Thanks, +1. I solved this by doing the HTML to send UTF-8 stuff to my cgi script, but that was not my question so I'll accept this.

Answer (score 2):

You can prefix your string with a `u` to mark it as a unicode literal:

```
>>> a = u'm\xe9dico'
>>> print a
médico
>>> type(a)
<type 'unicode'>
```

or, to convert an existing string:

```
>>> a = 'm\xe9dico'
>>> type(a)
<type 'str'>
>>> new_a = unicode(a,'iso-8859-1')
>>> print new_a
médico
>>> type(new_a)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> new_a == u'm\xe9dico'
True
```

Further reading: [Python docs - Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm not defining `a`, the `cgi` module is doing that.

Comment: Thanks, that works. But this returns `False`: `a == u"médico"`. Any ideas?

Comment: You'll get `True` if you compare it with `new_a`, it will probably fail to convert `a` automatically.

Comment: I was doing something wrong. Thanks for your time. I put your answer +1.